# Xcode cannnot find my plist file when building

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist

I'm trying to build my app and every time I do I get this error:

> error: The file "Wallpapers-Info.plist" does not exist.

Anyone know what causes this error?  I have the wallpaper-info.plist file in my resources directory.

Comment: When you look at your files in Xcode, is Wallpapers-Info.plist red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the wallpaper-info.plist file in my resources directory.

The error indicates that Xcode is looking for a file called "Wallpaper*s*-Info.plist". Are you sure you named the file correctly?

Comment: Wallpapers-Info.plist

That's copied directly from finder.

Comment: Hmmm...for whatever reason it appears that plist file cannot be placed in a subfolder.

Comment: It can be -- you just have to make sure that Xcode knows the proper path to it. Perhaps when you added it it *wasn't* in a subdirectory, and then you moved it?

Answer (score 8):

The value of the Info.plist File build setting in your Target Settings has to be a partial path, relative to the project directory, to the Info.plist file.  If you move or rename the Info.plist file, you have to change the value of the build setting.  So if you placed the Info.plist file in Resources, set the build setting to Resources/Wallpapers-Info.plist .